# What exactly is outer/inner region and outer/inner solution?

Tags: perturbation-theory

I have been searching in some literature and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_matched_asymptotic_expansions) about the definition or explanation of outer region, outer solution, inner region and inner solution of boundary layer theory, perturbation theory and asymptotic matching. But I could not find any useful and easily understood one.

In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_matched_asymptotic_expansions), it is written **An approximation in the form of an asymptotic series is obtained in the transition layer(s) by treating that part of the domain as a separate perturbation problem. This approximation is called the "inner solution," and the other is the "outer solution"**

I don't find this explanation clear enough. I am a bit confused what exactly is outer/inner region and outer/inner solution? Is it correct if I interpret outer and inner as outside the boundary and inside the boundary? But again, a question arises, where is considered as outside/inside? Does it have any relationship with the order of $\epsilon$, that is $O(\epsilon)$? Such as the limit as $\epsilon\to0$ or something like that?

I would just want some easily understood and not so deep explanation since I am quite immature in this field. I apologise for such a naive question, this idea has always been so vague to me, I just want to get a better understanding. I will really appreciate if anyone would like to provide some explanations and share some insights.

Thanks!

Comment: A proper answer for this will not be short, so for now I will just address a minor point of terminology: The inner solution/region refers to inside the *boundary layer*, not the boundary itself. And the outer solution/region is then outside the boundary layer. The inner solution has a short length scale; the outer solution, a longer one. Note that there is a fuzzy transition between the inner and outer regions, where matching takes place.

Answer (score 4):

This is perhaps best illustrated by an example. Consider the ODE with boundary values
$$\varepsilon y''+(1-\varepsilon)y'-y=0,\qquad y(0)=0,\quad y(1)=1.$$
The exact solution is easily found:
$$ y=\frac{e^x-e^{-x/\varepsilon}}{e-e^{-1/\varepsilon}}.$$
Basically, the $e^x$ part will be the *outer* solution. It has the natural length scale $1$, and is approximately valid in most of the interval $[0,1]$, i.e., where $x\gg\varepsilon$. Not coincidentally, $e^{x-1}$ solves
$$y'-y=0,\qquad y(1)=1$$
which is the original problem with $\varepsilon=0$ and one boundary condition thrown away.
And the reason for the lost boundary condition is that it is inside the *inner* region, defined by $x\lesssim\varepsilon$. Inside the inner region the problem has a much shorter length scale, and in fact the behaviour solution is dominated by the $e^{-x/\varepsilon}$ part (but one must not forget the $e^x$ part – just notice that $e^x\approx1$ in the inner region, so it is quite “tame”).

Typically, one finds the inner solution by rescaling the problem to fit the natural length scale of the inner region; in this case, $\varepsilon$. So use $X=x/\varepsilon$ as the new length scale. Put $Y(X)=y(x)$ and rewrite the original problem to
$$Y''+(1-\varepsilon)Y'-\varepsilon Y=0,\qquad Y(0)=0,$$
where I have thrown away the other boundary condition, which would be $Y(1/\varepsilon)=1$. That is too far outside the inner region to be useful.

To a zeroth approximation this becomes
$$Y''+Y'=0,\qquad Y(0)=0,$$
with a general solution $Y(X)=C(1-e^{-X})$.

The remaining problem is to match up inner and outer solutions in order to determine $C$.
This may done by appealing to $x$ in the intermediate region, where $x\gg\varepsilon$ but still $x\ll1$, where $X\gg1$, so the inner solution will be ${}\approx C$ while the outer solution is ${}\approx e^{-1}$, thus leading to $C=e^{-1}$.

So for this example, in summary: The inner region is $x\lesssim\varepsilon$, the inner solution is $e^{-1}(1-e^{-x/\varepsilon})$, the outer region is $x\gg\varepsilon$, and the outer solution is $e^{x-1}$. All this just to lowest order, of course.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. There is a point that I don't quite understand, why is $e^x$ valid for $x\gg\epsilon$ ? Thanks :)

Comment: Because the other term, $e^{-x/\varepsilon}$, is negligible in that case.

Comment: I see thanks! Also after you substitute $X=x/\epsilon$ and $Y(X)=y(x)$ should there be a coefficient of $1/\epsilon$ in front of $Y''$ ?

Comment: I don't think so, as I had silently multiplied the whole equation by $\varepsilon$ after doing the substitution. (Sorry about the silence; I just wanted to keep the length down.)

Comment: Oh yes, you are right! how careless, thanks!